# Maclaurin series for the function $f(x) = \ln\left(\frac{|x^2 - 1|}{x+1}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I want to find the Maclaurin series (Taylor at $0$) for the following function:

$f(x) = \ln\left(\frac{|x^2 - 1|}{x+1}\right)$

So far I have worked on this solution but I am not sure if it's correct:

$$
f(x) = \ln\left(\frac{|x^2 - 1|}{x+1}\right) = \ln(|x^2-1|) - \ln|x+1| = \ln|x-1|+\ln|x+1| - \ln|x+1|
= \ln|x-1| = \ln|1-x| 
$$

Since we are around zero I think that we can can drop the absolute value and evaluate
$$
\ln|1-x| = \ln(1-x) = -\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}
$$

If the solution is not correct, could you suggest an alternative solution, please?

Comment: You should drop the absolute value right at the beginning: $ln \frac{1-x^2}{1+x}=ln \frac{(1-x)(1+x)}{1+x}=ln (1-x)$

Comment: @Jean Marie Okay, thanks!